# Using R - how to find correlation of the ordered pairs after standardization?

Tags: r, correlation, standardized

Suppose, I have the following ordered data sets:

```
X <- c(12, 15, 23, 4, 9, 36, 10, 16, 67, 45, 58, 32, 40, 58, 33) 

# and 

Y <- c(1.5, 3.3, 10, 2.1, 8.3, 6.3, 4, 5.1, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 3.1, 2.2, 4, 3)
```

**What does it mean by "the correlation of their ordered pairs after standardization"?**

**How to find (code for) it in R?**

Comment: You can standardize matrices/vectors in **R** with `scale(x)` and you can find the correlation between two vectors with `cor(x,y)`. Hence what you are asked for is (maybe?) `cor(scale(X),scale(Y))`, but scaling and standardization is irrelevant for the correlation, i.e. you get the same result by `cor(X,Y)`.

Comment: @Therkel, it seems you did not understand the context of the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to standardize the given sets for X and Y, We will first 
calculate average, variance, standard deviation of population.

In next step, we need to subtract each individual value in each
set from its mean and then in final step, we need to divide the
values obtained, from 2nd step, by its standard deviation, which
is nothing but a Z-scores of the set (and individual value, say Xi).
Doing so, we will get mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1 for both
X and Y sets.

This is standardized condition because we will always get **mean as zero and standard deviation as one** for all of the sets (in your case X and Y).

We will also look into the relationships between ordered pairs.

If we look at certain standard relationship such as co-variance
correlation, the slope is best fit line that plots Y against X,
then the Y intercept will they be the same for the original 
values and the standardized values or will they be different?
And if they be different, how different will they be and why?

This was the context of question.

**What I tried in R is as follows:**

**Your Data Set is:**

```
X <- c(12, 15, 23, 4, 9, 36, 10, 16, 67, 45, 58, 32, 40, 58, 33) 
# and 
Y <- c(1.5, 3.3, 10, 2.1, 8.3, 6.3, 4, 5.1, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 3.1, 2.2, 4, 3)
```

**Statistics for Original Data, where n = 15 observations for X and Y each**

```
# Variance
VarX <- sum((X - mean(X))^2)/15    ## Which gives us Variance of X set as 374.5156
VarY <- sum((Y - mean(Y))^2)/15    ## Which gives us Variance of Y set as 6.226489

# Standard Deviation
sdX <- sqrt(VarX)       ## Which gives us Std. Dev. of X set as 19.3524
sdY <- sqrt(VarY)       ## Which gives us Std. Dev. of Y set as 2.495293

# Z-scores
Z_Score_X <- (X - mean(X))/sdX
Z_Score_Y <- (Y - mean(Y))/sdY

# A Check, mean of ZScores should be close or equal to 0 
# and Std. Dev. must be close or equal to 1
round(mean(Z_Score_X), 0)         # Yes, it is 0
round(sd(Z_Score_X), 0)           # Yes, it is 1
round(mean(Z_Score_Y), 0)         # Yes, it is 0
round(sd(Z_Score_Y), 0)           # Yes, it is 1
```

**This is the standardized condition where we have same mean 
and standard deviation for both X and Y (as in above cases of Z Score data set).**

Now we will look into the relationships between ordered pairs
If we look at certain standard relationship such as coveriance
correlation, the slope is best fit line that plots Y against X,
then the Y intercept will they be the same for the original 
values and the standardized values or will they be different?
And if they be different, how different wil they be and why?

## Let's calculate the rest...

First we look at the co-variance of X and Y...
Covariance (X, Y) = (1/n) * summation(i = 1 to n) of products 
of (Xi - mean(X)) and (Yi - mean(Y))
and together, Xi and Yi are in ordered pair (remember step 3 above, 
the Z-Scores)

```
# Covariance for older sets (X, Y)
covXY <- (1/15) * sum((X - mean(X))*(Y - mean(Y)))

# Covariance for New sets (Z_Score_X, Z_Score_Y)
covXYZ <- (1/15) * sum((Z_Score_X - mean(Z_Score_X))*(Z_Score_Y - mean(Z_Score_Y)))
```

Next we will look at slope (Beta) of best fit line of (X and Y)

Recall, **Beta = slope = delta_Y / delta_X**

```
# Slope for old set (X, Y)
Beta_X_Y  <- round(lm(Y ~ X)$coeff[[2]], 2)

# Slope for standardized values in new set (Z_Score_z, Z_Score_z1)
Beta_ZScoreXY <- round(lm(Z_Score_X ~ Z_Score_Y)$coeff[[2]], 2)
```

Please note that intercept for the standardized values will always be ZERO
The reason for that is because the means for standardized values are always
on the best fit line and are zero (as in our case of Z_Score_X, Z_Score_Y, 
the means are 0, 0).
In other words, the best fit line, for standardized data, must go through origin.
Although, not always necessary, but it is expected so.

```
# Intercept for old set
Intercept_X_Y <- round(lm(Y ~ X)$coeff[[1]], 2) 
# 5.17

# Intercept for standardized set, should be zero
Intercept_ZScore_X_Y <- round(lm(Z_Score_Y ~ Z_Score_X)$coeff[[1]], 2) 
# Yes, it is 0
```

Finally, we will look at Correlation, which is equal to
Covariate of X and Y divided by standard deviation of X times standard deviation of Y

```
# Correlation of old set
CorrelationXY <- round(covXY / (sdX * sdY), 2)

# Variance for new set
VarZScoreX <- sum((Z_Score_X - mean(Z_Score_X))^2)/15
VarZScoreY <- sum((Z_Score_Y - mean(Z_Score_Y))^2)/15 
sdZScoreX <- sqrt(VarZScoreX)
sdZScoreY <- sqrt(VarZScoreY)

# Correlation of new set
correlation_ZScore_X_Y <- round(covXYZ / (sdZScoreX * sdZScoreY), 2)
```

Therefore, what we see here is, that overall thing that remains constant
for old set of data or new set of standardized (z score) data, is the
correlation (in our case it is -0.34). The correlation is UNCHANGED.
One another point to note, for every standardized set, the slope, the
covariance are EQUAL to correlation (all -0.34 in our case) and the intercept
of standardized set is equal to zero.

Comment: Yes Manoj you are right. I might be poor in explaining. I am also waiting for R codes, if you could.

Comment: Wow... Awesome explanation... thanks for your time to code and resolve my problems... Impressive.